# Golang: Slice and make

Tags: go, slice

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSD8V.png)

I'm very confuse why is that after line 68, b is changed also. I was going to presume that when it came to line64, variable b were being set to refer "a"'s memory address.

```
a := make([]int, 5, 10)
fmt.Println("a=", a)
b := append(a, 1)
fmt.Println("000000000000000000000000")
fmt.Println("b=", b)
fmt.Println("a=", a)
c := append(a, 2)
fmt.Println("------------------------------")
fmt.Println("a=", a)
fmt.Println("b=", b)
fmt.Println("b[0]=", b[0])
fmt.Println("c=", c)
d := append(c, 5)
fmt.Println("///////////////////////////////")
fmt.Println("a=", a)
fmt.Println("b=", b)
fmt.Println("b[0]=", b[0])
fmt.Println("c=", c)
fmt.Println("d=", d)
-------------terminal------------------------
------------------------------------
a= [0 0 0 0 0]
000000000000000000000000
b= [0 0 0 0 0 1]
a= [0 0 0 0 0]
------------------------------
a= [0 0 0 0 0]
b= [0 0 0 0 0 2]
b[0]= 0
c= [0 0 0 0 0 2]
///////////////////////////////
a= [0 0 0 0 0]
b= [0 0 0 0 0 2]
b[0]= 0
c= [0 0 0 0 0 2]
d= [0 0 0 0 0 2 5]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

In which, I do particularly print "a" to see if a has been changed.

As you can see, variable "a" hasn't been changed at all. So I take it as my understanding that "append" fun is going to copy slice "a"'s value adding element on the final index of slice a.

Then, I can't see any chance of it that I give variable c = append(a, 2), and it will change variable b.

So here is my three question:

1. How is that I manipulate var c which changes var b
2. If "a" is an address or pointer type or some..else, why is that "a" has never been changed.
3. Even if b is reference an address value of something, why is after line 68 the C's value is not

[0 0 0 0 0 1 2]

And there is another picture here [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cshny.png)

```
    a := []int{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
//a := make([]int, 5, 10)
fmt.Println("a=", a)
b := append(a, 1)
fmt.Println("000000000000000000000000")
fmt.Println("b=", b)
fmt.Println("a=", a)
c := append(a, 2)
fmt.Println("------------------------------")
fmt.Println("a=", a)
fmt.Println("b=", b)
fmt.Println("b[0]=", b[0])
fmt.Println("c=", c)
d := append(c, 5)
fmt.Println("///////////////////////////////")
fmt.Println("a=", a)
fmt.Println("b=", b)
fmt.Println("b[0]=", b[0])
fmt.Println("c=", c)
fmt.Println("d=", d)
------terminal------------------------
------------------------------------
a= [0 0 0 0 0]
000000000000000000000000
b= [0 0 0 0 0 1]
a= [0 0 0 0 0]
------------------------------
a= [0 0 0 0 0]
b= [0 0 0 0 0 1]
b[0]= 0
c= [0 0 0 0 0 2]
///////////////////////////////
a= [0 0 0 0 0]
b= [0 0 0 0 0 1]
b[0]= 0
c= [0 0 0 0 0 2]
d= [0 0 0 0 0 2 5]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Why is that when I change make to normal declaration, every print log comes to make sense?
So is that secret inside the "make" ?

Comment: Dont post image of code; Edit your question and add the code here

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava  edited. thanks!!

Comment: https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro

Comment: Take the Tour of Go and read the slice blog post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Slices are references to underlying array; you can consider it like a struct
having values

1. Reference address to start of value in underlying array
2. Length of referenced by slice

Code:

```
func main() {
    a := make([]int, 5, 10)
    fmt.Println("a=", a)
    fmt.Println("Appending to a store in b")
    b := append(a, 1)
    fmt.Println("b=", b)
    fmt.Println("a=", a)
    
    fmt.Println("Appending to a store in c")
    c := append(a, 2)
    fmt.Println("a=", a)
    fmt.Println("b=", b)
    fmt.Println("c=", c)
    
    fmt.Println("Appending to c store in d")
    d := append(c, 5)
    
    fmt.Println("a=", a)
    fmt.Println("b=", b)
    fmt.Println("c=", c)
    fmt.Println("d=", d)
}
```

It is same code i just edited some println(s)

Now lets break down the output

Firstly you make an array of length 5 and max capacity of 10

```
a= [0 0 0 0 0]
```

This is as expected array of length 5

Now you append 1 to a and store in b
Means underlying array is now

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
|-------------| This part is referenced by a
|----------------| This part is referenced by b
```

So when you print this is exact output you get

```
Appending to a store in b
b= [0 0 0 0 0 1]
a= [0 0 0 0 0]
```

Now In next part you append to a now remember a only references 5 values in underlying array so when you append to a and store in c it updates underlying array index 5 and overwrites it

Before

```
[0,0,0,0,0,1]
```

After

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]
|-------------| This part is referenced by a
|----------------| This part is referenced by b
|----------------| This part is referenced by c  



Appending to a store in c
a= [0 0 0 0 0]
b= [0 0 0 0 0 2]
c= [0 0 0 0 0 2]
```

Now you append to c and it adds 5 to underlying array
Before

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]
```

After

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5]
|-------------| This part is referenced by a
|----------------| This part is referenced by b
|----------------| This part is referenced by c
|-------------------| This part is referenced by d  



Appending to c store in d
a= [0 0 0 0 0]
b= [0 0 0 0 0 2]
c= [0 0 0 0 0 2]
d= [0 0 0 0 0 2 5]
```

Hope it makes it clear :)

Comment: Im so sorry
I didn't get it in where you mention 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1] |-------------| This part is referenced by a |----------------| This part is referenced by b
Why is that [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1] is referenced by a, still I print a and it comes [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

and the following has the same confuse.

thanks again

Comment: @Eien_ZhengYC_    it gor misformatted i will fix that

Comment: @Eien_ZhengYC_ is it understandable now

Comment: You just need to understand that job of slice is to point at starting and ending point of a part of array it does this by containing reference to start position and length from that position

Comment: much better now~  let me think about it

Comment: Hahaha thank you I got this logic. !!!!But the second problem come along with is this logic seems doesn't work in my second part of code, which is use a := []int{0, 0, 0, 0, 0} to create part. Very appreciate!

Comment: I want !!! But I couldn't find the place where to accept the answer.  I do apologize

Comment: @Eien_ZhengYC_ https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288/dealing-with-an-answer-that-wasnt-accepted-maybe-because-a-user-is-a-newbie-on/251298#251298